# Cannot get Library First Aid to open using Option + Command in iPhoto

Tags: photos.app

I am migrating a bunch of iPhone libraries from one drive to another, repairing them along the way, and migrating them to the Photos app.

However, I cannot get the "Library First Aid" windows to open following the [instructions provided by Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201769) to hold Option + Command while opening iPhoto:

> 1. Quit iPhoto if it is open.
> 2. Hold down the Command and Option keys on the keyboard.
> 3. Open iPhoto.
> 4. Keep the keys held down until you are prompted to rebuild the library.
> 5. A dialog will appear with rebuild options. Select the options you want to use.

For me, the library opens, and I continue holding down the keys but the dialog never opens (minutes later even).

I am running iPhoto 9.6.1.